# How to assign ajax response to Variables

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have drop down Select box as follows

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT scheduleName FROM schedule";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
echo "<select name='schedule' id='schedule'>";
echo "<option value=''>-- Select Schedule --</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['scheduleName'] . "'>" . $row['scheduleName'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
```

And I have a file called **processClg.php** as follows

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if ($_POST['type']=='POST')
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE scheduleName LIKE 'Row id of drop down selection'";
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$qry);
}
?>
```

---

How can I call processClg.php file on `$("#schedule").change(function ());`by assigning Row id of drop down selection as where condition.

---

**Update**

Am getting Response from processClg.Php as follows

`[{"id":"2","scheduleName":"shanth","subject":"Patho","university":"Dali","facultyName":"Dr","scheduleStartDate":"2015-06-05","scheduleEndDate":"2015-06-09"}]`

How to assign response values from ajax call to the following Php variables

```
  <?php
$scheduleStartDate = '';
$scheduleEndDate = '';
?>
```

Any help my greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use ajax and pass the value in `data:{rowid:$('select :selected').val()}`

Comment: Can you please suggest some code, How can I get values for the variables `$scheduleStartDate = ''; ` and `$scheduleEndDate = '';`  from ajax response.

Comment: @Selva  in network it is showing Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\xampp\htdocs\students\processClg.php on line 3

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#schedule").change(function() {
    var value = $('#schedule option:selected').text();
    var ajaxCheck = $.ajax({
        url: 'processClg.php',
        type: 'POST', // had mention post bcoz u mention in processClg.php
        dataType: 'json', // processClg.php will return string means change to text
        data: { id: value },
        success: function(data){
            console.log('success');
            itrToRead(data);
        }
    });
});

function itrToRead(data) {
    $(data).each(function(key, value){
        console.log('key is: '+key+' and value is: '+value);
    });
}
```

**processClg.php**

```
<?php
    include "config.php";
    if ($_POST['type']=='POST') {
        $qry = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE scheduleName LIKE '".$_POST['id']."'";
        $res = mysqli_query($link,$qry);
        echo $res;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Can you please update with your code what exactly I need to write as am new webie i have less knowledge about ajax

Comment: @Nag can u tell the parameters u will pass to `processClg.php`

Comment: id of drop down selection `echo "<option value='" . $row['scheduleName'] . "'>" . $row['scheduleName'] . "</option>";`

Comment: i am asking this post or get method, what are prameters u will pass to `processClg.php`

Comment: I don't know how to pass prameters through ajax please help me

Comment: @Nag what parameters u need, eg if u need dropdown selected value means copy paste the whole code will works fine

Comment: @Nag u will do in php like $_POST['id'] you will get like this know, like wise what are the value you will get there, u send in data{}, u can receive there by $_POST[''];

Comment: am expecting to send the id of drop down selection onchange to `processClg.php` to query the data base.

Comment: @Nag `$(this).attr('id');` will select selected id onchangen, i updated code, now id of selected drop dow will send to `processClg.php`

Comment: @Nag now u understand, u will send selected id by assigning to value and sending to `processClg.php`, there u should receive as $_POST['id'];

Comment: @Nag can u tell me what u wiil return from 'processClg.php'

Comment: @ Selva i'm checking can you please post how my  procellClg.php will be

Comment: @ Selva am expecting to return `scheduleName`,`scheduleStartDate` and `scheduleEndDate`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80275/discussion-between-selva-and-nag).

Comment: @Nag then return as associative array that is json it will be simple. u can easily iterate in jquery

Answer (score 0):

You can call ajax as follows:

```
    var RowId;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: url,
        data: postdata,
        //dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            RowId = data;
        }
    });
```

The fact is that to assign response to variable is pass the parameter `async: false,`

Then its work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have your dropdown in your rendered page and you want to send the selected value to the php page:

```
$("#schedule").change(function(){
    var val2pass = $(this).find(':selected').val(); // get the value
    $.ajax({
      url: 'processClg.php',
      type:'post', // <-----you need to use post as you are using $_POST[]
      data: { rowid : val2pass }, //<---pass the value
      success: function(data){
          itrToRead(data);
      }
   });
});
```

So now on the php side you need to do this:

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if ($_POST['type']=='POST')
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE scheduleName LIKE '".$_POST['rowid']."'";
    $res = mysqli_query($link,$qry);
}
?>
```

Comment: am getting drop down values from database, and I tried your code  How can I get values for the variables `$scheduleStartDate = ''; and $scheduleEndDate = '';` from ajax response

Answer (score 0):

Your procellClg.php will be

```
<?php
include "config.php";
if (isset($_REQUEST['qid']))
{
    $qry = "SELECT * FROM schedule WHERE scheduleName LIKE '".$_REQUEST['qid']."'";
    $result = mysqli_query($link,$qry);
echo "<select name='schedule' id='schedule'>";
echo "<option value=''>-- Select Schedule --</option>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "<option value='" . $row['scheduleName'] . "'>" . $row['scheduleName'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
}
?>
```

and then make Ajax function call

```
$("#schedule").change(function() {  
val = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        async: false,
        url: 'processClg.php',
        data: {qid:val},
        success: function(data){
            $(this).html(data);
        }
    });
});
```